# Predictions on statistical series

Tags: probability, data-mining

I need to summarize possible approaches (as well as their pros and cons) to the problem of statistical series prediction.

It's pure theoretical question, an example below was given only for convenience and specificity.

First of all, sorry for the term 'statistical series'. Question originally asked in another language, and I had hard time translating it. But what kind of series it is should be obvious from example.

An example represents series of dice throwing experiment. We have 20 observations and the observed frequency distribution is described by the table below.

$\begin{matrix} \text{dice face} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \text{sum} & 2 & 6 & 8 & 2 & 1 & 1\\ 
\text{frequency} & 0.1 & 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.1 & 0.05 & 0.05\end{matrix}$

Let's return to our task now. We have to derive some predictive model now.
I was able to think of only 1 approach:

- We calculate standard error and mean, then able to make and prove any hypothesis about future observations with use of t-test. A negative aspect of this approach is the involvement of uncertainty in the answer (confidence intervals, etc.)

When I  gave it further thought, I may not understand very good process of prediction here. If continue sampling, our histogram will get more and more precise, but what would be the value to predict at first place? density function, population mean?

Due to last paragraph, I don't see data mining machinery applicable here  (regressions, neural nets, decision trees).

I would appreciate insights and clarifications.

Comment: You can use a model for the data (parametric or not) and fit the model to the data using [MLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood) for example

Comment: Another one is a [linear prediction model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_prediction) of the data, being simplest (more elaborate models of course exist)

Comment: It's not actually clear what you're trying to achieve here. What are you 'predicting'? What's the aim?